# using Meachanize to download csv file

Tags: perl, csv, download

i need my program to go to finance.yahoo.com and download historical prices of AAPl (and 4 others... later) to a csv file. (that it gonna load into database... also later) 
i need this program to start every evening, download the file and insert it into db. 
problem is - i cant figure what link should i use in the script so it is the same every day, well and the script itself. i tried  this

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use WWW::Mechanize;
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new;
my $url = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=AAPL+Historical+Prices';
$mech->get($url);

my $local_file_name ='AAPL.csv';
$mech->follow_link( url_regex => qr/Download/i );
$mech->get( $url, ":content_file" => $local_file_name );
```

it actually downloads smth and stores it into AAPl.csv - but its nonsense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::Simple qw(getstore);

my @date = split(/\s+/, scalar localtime);
my %month = ('Jan'=> 0, 'Feb'=> 1, 'Mar'=> 2, 'Apr'=>3, 'May'=>4,
    'Jun'=>5, 'Jul'=> 6, 'Aug' =>7, 'Sep'=>8, 'Oct'=>9, 'Nov'=>10, 'Dec'=>11);
my $url = 'http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=AAPL&d=$month{$date[1]}&e=$date[2]&f=$date[4]&g=d&a=8&b=7&c=1984&ignore=.csv';
getstore($url, "AAPL.csv");
```

I got the link from the actual download link. Since I had the link it made LWP::Simple seem like a better choice here.